# Generating Models from DB in Yii?

Tags: mysql, yii

Is there a way to automatically generate models from a MySQL DB in YII?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii) to generate models, views and controllers for [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations from tables.

You can enable Gii by inserting this code in your configuration file (uncomment it from the by yiic generated code).

```
'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'****',
            'ipFilters'=>false, // Not recommended, but easy.
      ),
),
```

Then browse to example.com/index.php?r=gii. Login to Gii and from there the process speaks from itself.

When asked for the Model name enter `*` to create models for all tables in the database.

Comment: +1 <- it's an half-automatic-model creation: Gii generates one model from one table, but Gii doesn't work in "batch mode". That means: it's not possible to generate models for all the tables at ones. You have to create the models step by step.

Comment: I know for a fact that I've auto-generated models before on Yii.
Sadly I don't remember how

Comment: Yii has (er, "had", it's been depreciated in favor of Gii) a command line tool for this, that could be called by a shell script or something to make it more "automatic". Or it could be modified to be more automatic. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app-yiic

Comment: @The Bndr. not true. Just enter * for the model name and it will generate models for all tables.

Comment: @the bndr schemaname.* will generate all the models.  I'll recommended updating your yii framework copy.

Comment: @el chief , @k to the z  thank you for that helpful information!!

Comment: @el chief, @k to the z: I added your comments to the answer.